# Grails - combine errors in command object and subobjects

Tags: grails, command-objects

I checked out [Grails: How to combine domain objects' errors with command objects' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366168/grails-how-to-combine-domain-objects-errors-with-command-objects-errors), but for some reason the solutions aren't working for me. It's possible they're only for Grails 1.3.7 and not Grails 2.2.1.

I have a command object OuterObjectCommand that contains a list of InnerObjectCommand. I'm populating it manually in the controller, and then calling validate. Calling validate() on OuterObjectCommand does not appear to be validating the InnerObjectCommand list, so I validate all the elements of the list separately. What I want to do is add all the errors of InnerObjectCommand objects and the OuterObjectCommand object into flash.errors. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using custom [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) in the outer command object which would  explicitly validate the inner command objects?

Comment: I'm not sure how to write that. static constraints = { innerObjectCommand validator: { it.validate(); ??? }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the last example in the [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) page.

Vaguely, you would need something like below:

```
class ParentCommand {
    List<ChildCommand> childCommands
    static constraints = {
        childCommands validator: {val, obj ->
            def errors = []
            val.each{
                 errors << (!it.validate() ? it.errors.allErrors : [])
            }

            errors?.flatten()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I'm looking into it, but any ideas on why that might happen?

Comment: @Anonymous1 I am not sure what the reason would be unless I see the implementation.

Comment: print "Errors: ${errors}" is outputting "Errors: [[], []]" if that helps any.